# C# Proper way to pass credentials between an Win form and a Win service

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I am fairly new to C#, so please be gentle :)

What I would like to accomplish is to create an application so that a certain team here at work is able to modify certain DNS entries. For security reasons we are not able to give their Active Directory user accounts modify access to DNS and we are trying to get away from changing the DNS entries for them as it is consuming a lot of our time.

So I have created a Windows Service with several methods to get and modify DNS entries, and a Windows Form that uses the Windows Service methods. The intention is to have the Windows Service run under a Active Directory User Account (Service Account), which has modify access to DNS and have the Windows Form run under their normal User Account.

Everything works fine if I run the Form as my Admin Account (which has modify access to DNS), but when I run the form under my normal User Account (which does not have modify access to DNS), I get the Exception,

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o)
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Initialize()
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()
   at ChangeDNS.ChangeDNSService.getCName(String cName) in C:\Tools\Projects\ChangeDNSService\ChangeDNSService\Program.cs:line 58
```

I am having trouble finding references or examples to shed some light to what I am missing and what the proper way to pass credentials between a Form and a Windows Service is. Could you please help point me in the right direction, as it would be much appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,

Darian

Edit:

The Form has the following code,

```
ServiceReference1.ChangeDNSClient dnsClient = new ServiceReference1.ChangeDNSClient();
            dnsClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

Console.WriteLine(dnsClient.getCName("TestDarianCName1"));
```

The Service has the following code,

```
public string getCName(string cName)
{
    serviceLog.Source = serviceName;
        string returnServer = "";

    try
        {
            ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();

        ManagementScope oMs = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + dnsServer + "\\root \\microsoftdns", connection);
                string strQuery = "select * from microsoftdns_" + recType + "Type where containername = '" + domain + "' and OwnerName = '" + cName + "." + domain + "'";
                ManagementObjectSearcher oS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(strQuery);
                oS.Scope = oMs;
                ManagementObjectCollection oRc = oS.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject oR in oRc)
                {
                    returnServer = oR["RecordData"].ToString();
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            serviceLog.WriteEntry("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());
        }

    return returnServer;
}
```

It think I am getting the error on the line ManagementObjectCollection oRc = oS.Get();

EDIT2:

Client Binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IChangeDNS" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8216/ServiceChangeDNS/service"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IChangeDNS"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IChangeDNS" name="WSHttpBinding_IChangeDNS">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/MyComputerName.domain.local" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Service Binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ChangeDNSServiceBehavior" name="ChangeDNS.ChangeDNSService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ChangeDNS.IChangeDNS" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8216/ServiceChangeDNS/service" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ChangeDNSServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The error provided sounds like it was to be expected, no? Said your AD user account doesn't have access, so when you run it as your normal account you're getting an access denied error... Not really sure what the problem is. Post some sample code / re-explain the problem? Are you just trying to make the application run using a different account completely?

Comment: Quote: "which does not have modify access to DNS".  What else would you expect to happen?  "Access is denied" means "does not have modify access".

Comment: @sab669 - Sorry if I wasn't clear, I am trying to use the credentials of the service account to modify the DNS, instead of the credentials of the user. So User runs form from their account which calls the service which has the proper credentials to modify DNS

Comment: @Hans Passant - I would like to try to have the Windows Service modify DNS or somehow have the Form get the credentials from the Windows Service so that it can impersonate the credentials of the service account

Comment: Then configure the service to run with an account that allows it to make these modifications.

Comment: The service is running with an account that has modify access to DNS. I will post some of my code.

Comment: Maybe consider instead of using the service, which runs under the privileged account and adds an extra layer of complexity and confusion to your app, just forget about the service and instead put all the DNS code directly into the form, and then have the form programmatically impersonate the privileged user before it searches/modifies DNS?  There are plenty of impersonation examples on stackoverflow to take from.

Comment: @dizzy.stackoverflow - Is it possible to programmatically impersonate the privileged user without hard coding the password into the Form's code?

Comment: Brain fart. You're absolutely right. Sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are requesting impersionation on the client side. So then of course that the service will run in the users context and not in its own. You either remove the impersonation on the client side and if you need it for something perform it just for that call then.

Comment: I removed the impersonation from the client side and am still getting the same error.

Comment: you have to check that your service does not require to allways do impersonation. Post here your service wcf binding that you are using.

Comment: Hopefully that is what you were looking for. Thanks

Comment: If you check in the service for: ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name you can see that the user being your client user?

Comment: Yes, if I return ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name from the service back to the client, I can see that the user is the client user.